# How to verify two sets of vectors span the same subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

The paper [(Oja 1992)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0893608005800899) states that

> The convergence has been earlier studied by Williams (1985), who
> showed that [for the equation $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{x}\mathbf{W}^T$, if weight matrix $\mathbf{W}$ is updated using the update equation $$ \Delta \mathbf{W} = \mathbf{y}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{W}\mathbf{y}) $$ then, ] the weight
> vectors $w_1(k), \dots, w_p(k)$ [(columns of weight matrix $\mathbf{W}$)] will
> not tend to the eigenvectors $c_1, \dots, c_p$, [of the covariance
> matrix $\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^T$,] but only to a rotated basis in the subspace spanned by
> them.

1. How can one numerically verify that for a stream of data $\mathbf{x}^{(k)}$ (with $k$ the discrete time), vectors $w_1(k), \dots, w_p(k)$ span the same subspace as the eigenvectors $c_1, \dots, c_p$?
2. Let's assume the algorithm is not converged yet. Is there a metric that measures "how true" the statement above is? Or "How much do they span the same subspace".

Comment: If you have a matrix with columns $[w_1, \ldots, w_p, c_1, \ldots, c_p]$ and then you row-reduce it, it should happen that once you reduce all $w_i,$ the $c_j$ are numerically zero. I am unsure if this is the most effective way to do it but it is theoretically the way to go.

Comment: @WilliamM. Thank you. That may not be feasible here as each matrix $W$ and $C$ can be as large as 170x170.